# How to add a color layer to the image in paintComponent method?

Tags: java, image, swing

I write my first game in Java. So I have Board class extends JPanel, and inside this class I have paintComponent method. Cards images are BufferedImages.

Now... I just finished method, that calculate possible player moves. To clarify, I have enemy card Fields, and I want to add some layer to enemy cardField image every time when enemy CardField is within player move.

My code in paintComponent method is something like this:

```
if(!field.isWithinMove()){
//draw normal state card
  g.drawImage(field.getLoadedCard().getCardImage(),
  field.getX(), field.getY(), Card.cardWidth, Card.cardHeight, null);
}
else{
 //there should be a card picture with layer of color 
}
```

My goal is:

Normal:

[image: Normal]

Highlighted:

[image]

I will be grateful for your help :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

You could make use of a `AlphaComposite` to change the way in which the graphics are rendered, for example...

[image: Normal and highlighted]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(source of your image here);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication393.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(189 * 2, 270);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            // Normal
            g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
            // Highlighted
            g2d.drawImage(img, img.getWidth(), 0, this);
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
            g2d.setColor(UIManager.getColor("List.selectionBackground"));
            g2d.fillRect(img.getWidth(), 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Now, you could actually pre-render this (have a "normal" and "highlighted" image), but that comes down to your needs

*nb: I've used the `List.selectionBackground` color from the current look and feel for the fill color, you can replace it with what ever color you want*

Have a look at [Trail: 2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [Compositing Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html) for more details

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for alpha-component. Colors can be represented as RGB or RGBA. The difference is  that RGBA adds an additional channel for transparency. So basically you can paint a rectangle over the image using this additional channel:

```
...

Color overlay = new Color(0 , 0 , 200 , 
         150//alpha component
);

g.setColor(overlay);
g.fillRectangle(...);//fill in position of the image here
```

The higher the alpha composite, the higher the opacity of the color, where 255 is like painting with a traditional RGB color without alpha component and 0 is like not painting at all (fully transparent).